# Scrolldown in ListView using ItemAppearing event skips records in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview, xamarin.ios-binding

I have `ListView` in Xamarin Page. I use `ItemAppearing` event to scroll down. ListViewCell height is big so 1 screen cover first and 80% part of second viewcell.

Steps to load more data for scroll down:

1. Initially when page load, it call API and get 10 records in
   EmployerResult List. That will be added in ListView using
   databinding.
2. Having `ItemAppearing` event. There is a condition in this event.
   When last cell start to appear, it will call API and again append 10
   record in List object of ViewModel.
3. So, this way it will call to API and append 10 record everytime when
   last cell start to appear.

Now the point is on every load, it skips last record and show first record of next 10 record. However sometimes it skips 2-3 records if user scrolldown fastly.

i.e if I have 10 records first time. Now I am on 9th record and I am scrolling down to 10. 10th record is starting to appear and API call fires. After this call completed, screen will show 11th record at top of the screen. Here, 10th record is skipped. This way user will see 11th record rather 10th. Here user need to scrollup again to see 10th record.

Sometimes, it skips 2-3 records if user scrolldown fastly.

Can anybody please suggest me?

Code

XAML

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="EmployerResultsListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding EmployerResults}"
          HasUnevenRows = "true"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemAppearing="Handle_ItemAppearing"
          ItemTapped="OnEmployerResultsListViewItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:EmployerResultViewCell />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

XAML.CS

```
private void Handle_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
    var itemTypeObject = e.Item as EmployerProfile;
    if (_viewModel.EmployerResults.Last() == itemTypeObject && _viewModel.EmployerResults.Count() != 1)
    {
        if (_viewModel.LoadMoreCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            _viewModel.LoadMoreCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public EmployerResultsViewModel()
{
    LoadMoreCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadMoreEmployerResult, () => !IsBusy);
    EmployerResults = new ObservableRangeCollection<EmployerProfile>();
}
public ObservableRangeCollection<EmployerProfile> EmployerResults { get; set; }

private async void LoadMoreEmployerResult()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    EmployerResults.AddRange((await _employerApiClient.GetMoreData(pagenumber)));
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: Your question is the solution that I am looking for.

Comment: Brilliant idea but caused a lot of unstable scrolling and flickering on iOS

Comment: @Ashi This was working correctly back in 2018 when I had implemented this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is add additional blank cell at the end on `LoadMoreEmployerResult` and call for load more on appearing on that. On load more, I remove that blank cell. This is the only way I feel that can resolve my issue.

```
private async void LoadMoreEmployerResult()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    if(EmployerResults.Last().Name == "")
        EmployerResults.RemoveAt(EmployerResults.Count - 1);
    List<EmployerProfile> currentPageList= await _employerApiClient.GetMoreData(pagenumber);
    if(currentPageList.Count > 0)
    {
        EmployerResults.AddRange(currentPageList);
        EmployerResults.Add(new EmployerProfile());
    }

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, your are trying to do Lazy Loading.

-First, you should set the recycling Strategy like this: CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" if you want acceptable performances as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance, then re-test the behavior of the ItemAppearing event.

-Then, it may be a good idea to use or to analyze an existing component that handles your need. For example: http://15mgm15.ghost.io/2017/11/28/implement-an-infinite-scrolling-listview-with-xamarin-forms/